# Iterate across columns spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a data frame with three columns:"variable 1","variable 2", "correlations" from a given dataframe of 200 variables

Now for any two columns in a dataframe I am using the following code to calculate correlations

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics

// Generate some random data
scala.util.Random.setSeed(1)
val df = sc.parallelize(g.sample(1000).zip(g.sample(1000))).toDF("x", "y")


// Select columns and extract values
val rddX = df.select($"x").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))
val rddY = df.select($"y").rdd.map(_.getDouble(0))

val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(rddX, rddY, "spearman")
```

How I can I do the same for a set of x variables in the dataframe so as to find out the variables with highest correlations from the resulting dataframe

Comment: what is `g` exactly? and do you want correlations of all possible combinations of your columns?

Comment: Yes That is correct

Answer (score 2):

You should first convert your `RDD[Row]` to an `RDD[Vector]`, and then you can simply use `Statistics.corr()` with your `rdd` as the input argument to generate a correlation matrix:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val rdd_vec = df.rdd.map(row => {
  Vectors.dense(row.toSeq.toArray.map({
    case d: Double => d
  }))
})

val correlMatrix = Statistics.corr(rdd_vec, "spearman")
```